# Any function that is non-proximable and non-smooth?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Does anyone have any example, where

> a function that is both n[on-proximable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_operator) and non-smooth (in particular, non-[Lipschitz continuous gradient](http://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/Lipschitz-gradient))?

Comment: What are the definitions of 'proximable' and 'smooth'?

Comment: @gerw My bad for being sloppy. I have added some references to both proximal and non-smooth that I have in my mind

Comment: Ok, but what is 'proximable'? The link does only consider the proximal point mapping.

Comment: @gerw Thank you for your comment. As I understand for instance from this paper https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/51964772.pdf, which according to my interpretation is "proximable": a function whose proximal point mapping has closed-form solution?! Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You do not deliver a definition of "proximable", but I suspect that the function
$$
x \mapsto (f(x), g(x))$$
is neither proximable or smooth if $f$ is not proximable and $g$ is not smooth.